# ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined - error for 1 of 2 webpages that share same graph building function and html template

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I am working on Flask web application, where I am trying to include a Plotly scatter plot as part of two very similar webpages.

- The first page corresponds to a running experiment where an input time is editable, and the plot shows available results from experiment start and up to the current time.
- The second page corresponds to a completed experiment, where the same input fields are shown, now as read-only, and the same plot is done for the entire dataset for that experiment

Given the similarities I use 
- the same function to create the json code for the graph
- same html to define the div where the plot should show

### FUNCTION FOR CREATING THE JSON Graph

```py
def CreatePlot(experiment_name):
    query=Result.query.filter_by(experiment=experiment_name)
    results_df=pd.read_sql_query(query.statement, query.session.bind)
    ind=0
    color=["#2B4141","#B80C09","#0EB1D2","#8AEA92","#91CB3E","#E3C0D3","#6B2737"]

    fig = go.Figure()
    buttonslist=[dict(label="All",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True]*len(cf.resultlabels), 
                            }])]

    for label in cf.resultlabels:
        resultslabel=results_df.columns[ind+1]
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                        x=results_df['runningtime'], 
                        y=results_df[resultslabel], 
                        name=label, 
                        visible=True,
                        line=dict(color=color[ind])))
        visible=[False]*len(cf.resultlabels)
        visible[ind]=True
        buttonslist.append(dict(label=label,
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": visible}]))
        ind=ind+1


    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(active=0,buttons=list(buttonslist))], 
        xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(title=go.layout.xaxis.Title(text="Time (min)")))

    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    print(graphJSON)

    return graphJSON
```

### HTML:

#### Common html layout file for both webpages includes reference to plotl-latest.min.js and d3.js

```html
{% block head %}
  {% block refresh %}{% endblock refresh %}
   <script src={{ url_for('static', filename='js/plotly-latest.min.js') }}> 
   </script>
   <script src={{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.min.js') }}></script>
  {% endblock head %}
```

#### common code for plot: included in both experimentrun.html and experimentresults.html

```html
{% if plot!=None %}
    <div class="chart" id="scatter">
        <script>
            var graphs = {{plot | safe}};
            Plotly.plot('scatter',graphs,{});
        </script>
    </div> 
</div>
{% endif %}
```

### ROUTES:

#### page for running experiment

```py
@app.route("/experiment/<string:experiment_name>/running",methods=['GET','POST']) 
def exprun(experiment_name):

   experiment=Experiment.query.filter_by(name=experiment_name).first_or_404()    
   ...
    results=Result.query.filter_by(experiment=experiment.name).all()

    if results:
        #Generate results plot
        plot = CreatePlot(experiment.name)
    else:
        resultform=ResultTableForm()
        plot=None

    flash(resultform.errors)
    flash(form.errors)
    return render_template('experimentrun.html', form=form, resultform=resultform, forcesave=forcesave, runningtime=runningtime, plot=plot)
```

#### page for completed experiment

```py
@app.route("/experiment/<string:experiment_name>/completed",methods=['GET']) 
def expresults(experiment_name):
   experiment=Experiment.query.filter_by(name=experiment_name).first_or_404()
   ...    
    results=Result.query.filter_by(experiment=experiment.name).all()
    if results:
        #Generate results plot
        plot = CreatePlot(experiment.name)
    else:
        plot = None

    #General
    flash(form.errors)
    return render_template('experimentresults.html', form=form, plot=plot)
```

### ISSUE:

RUNNING route shows graphs as desired

I get Console error on COMPLETED route (using Chrome): 
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

I cannot figure out why it works in one case and not the other.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I started again step-by-step from the running route (that was working) html and realized that the issue is related with a page refresh block that I had on the running page but not on the completed one

```py
{% block refresh %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
{% endblock refresh %}
```

If I remove this block, the plotly graph no longer shows.
I can remove the content term, but not the http-equiv part.

```py
{% block refresh %}
<meta http-equiv="refresh">
{% endblock refresh %}
```

Although I solved the issue, I would like to know if anyone has an explanation for this.